# Is opening JBOSS-JMS port 1099/1098 compromises security?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, security

We am trying to send the chat messages to JMS queue. We are using JBoss for JMS.

Our JBoss is behind a secure gateway. If we open a port 1099/1098 (for JMS) at the gateway, does it become a security threat? If yes, how can we secure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application server should receive JMS messages from other servers on the other side of your firewall (I mean outside of your network) there is no other way to do so.
One possible solution is to restrict number of hosts from which connections to :1099/:1098 are accepted. You should know addresses of machines on which other servers which communicate with yours are deployed. Everything depends on type of firewall you use. If it's well-configured (i.e. restricts port access) modern deep inspection device it is very low probability that it will compromise security.

Comment: Thank you Piotrek, much appreciate your response.